# Android ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in inserting rows to mysql

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, sqlite

I'm getting an error in inserting rows to mysql table.

the records come from my local sqlite db. I currently have two records and want to insert them to mysql db.

Below is the code I'm working on:

```
    String[] arrDocumentNumber, arrTransactionDate, arrItemCode;

    arrDocumentNumber = dbHelper.getAllDocumentNumbersFromOUTTRANS();
    arrTransactionDate = dbHelper.getAllTransactionDatesFromOUTTRANS();
    arrItemCode = dbHelper.getAllItemCodesFromOUTTRANS();

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        for(int i = 0; i <= arrDocumentNumber.length; i++){

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DOCUMENTNUMBER, arrDocumentNumber[i] ));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TRANSACTIONDATE, arrTransactionDate[i] ));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ITEMCODE, arrItemCode[i] )); 

        }

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that insert outtrans url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_insertTo_outtrans,
                "POST", params);

 }
```

PHP:

```
 <?php
// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if ( isset($_POST['documentnumber']) && isset($_POST['transactiondate']) && isset($_POST['itemcode']) ){

    $documentnumber = $_POST['documentnumber'];
    $transactiondate = $_POST['transactiondate'];
    $itemcode = $_POST['itemcode'];

    // include db connect class
    include('dbconnect.php');

    $result = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO outtrans(documentnumber, transactiondate, itemcode) VALUES (:documentnumber, :transactiondate, :itemcode)");

    $result->bindParam(':documentnumber', $documentnumber);
    $result->bindParam(':transactiondate', $transactiondate);
    $result->bindParam(':itemcode', $itemcode);
    $result->execute();


    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "New record successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I'm getting error in this line:

```
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DOCUMENTNUMBER, arrDocumentNumber[i] ));
```

Any ideas? I'm really stuck on this problem. help is pretty much appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I changed to

```
   for(int i = 0; i < arrDocumentNumber.length; i++){
```

and it works, but the last record only saves into remote mysql db. It should save the two records I have from my local sqlite db.

Comment: for(int i = 0; i <= arrDocumentNumber.length; i++) should be for(int i = 0; i < arrDocumentNumber.length; i++)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the condition `<=` to `<`.

Bcs, for example if your `array` contains three elements, `length` of the `array` will be 3. So, the `for loop` should loop only three times. But, you have initialized your `i` as 0 and you have put the condition as `i <= arrDocumentNumber.length` so the `for will` loop totally four times till value of `i` becomes 3 from 0. So, it is throwing `ArrayindexOutofBoundexception`.

Either the condition should be :

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrDocumentNumber.length; i++)
```

or

```
for(int i = 1; i <= arrDocumentNumber.length; i++)
```

**Sample Code:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < arrDocumentNumber.length; i++){

params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DOCUMENTNUMBER, arrDocumentNumber[i] ));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_TRANSACTIONDATE, arrTransactionDate[i] ));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ITEMCODE, arrItemCode[i] )); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks this works but it only saves one record. I don't know why.

Comment: Yes I understand now but I wonder why it only saves the last record from my local db to remote mysql db.

Answer (score 1):

Array index should be less than array length. Change from

```
 for(int i = 0; i <= arrDocumentNumber.length; i++){
```

To,

```
 for(int i = 0; i < arrDocumentNumber.length; i++){
```

Comment: Thanks this works but it only saves one record. I don't know why

Comment: How many records in `arrDocumentNumber`?

Comment: There are 2 records in DocumentNumber

Comment: Probably your PHP code skip one record. I don't know much of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your for condition:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= arrDocumentNumber.length; i++){
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; **i < arrDocumentNumber.length;** i++){
```

**Less than**, **nor equal** and **less than**.

This raise the **exception**.

Comment: Thanks this works but it only saves one record. I don't know why

Comment: Could you please run a check on what values is the params list actually holding? Does it contain only one value or multiple values as required?   
If it contains the required values, please check the call to the function that actually inserts the values in the database.